# how to translate words/expressions in JS?

Tags: javascript, translation

I have 60 expressions and single words that i need to translate into English.

How can I design a simple (pure) JavaScript function to translate those 60 items? I need just an idea (design) not full code.

I wrote the 60 items to translate in English too. I just do not know how to link an item from one language to an other.

P.S. I do not want jQuery, Google Translate API and so on ... Just pure JavaScript.

Comment: What, like a dictionary of word translations?

Comment: yes, any idea, like the good one below

Comment: Show us your two word lists. If they're somwhow associated or sorted, you can map and merge two arrays or objects. It'd still be best if you shared some code.

Answer (score 3):

Put all your expressions in a map and use it to translate

```js
var languageMap = {
  "bonjour" : "Hello",
  "au revoir" : "Goodbye"
};

var word = "bonjour";
var inEnglish = languageMap[word];
console.log(word,"in english is",inEnglish)
```

Watch out, lookup here is case sensitive though. If you can't guarantee the casing of your input words you'll need something smarter.

Comment: very simple and smart idea. I was looking for something like that. You saved my life. Thank you!

Comment: And vice-versa?